# Intuitive RESTful API design for logistics shipments availability, accept, allocation decision?

Tags: design, rest, api-design

I am trying to model APIs for

- Create shipments
- Fetch Available shipments (based on region preferences)
- Accept shipments (allows logged in user to accept multiple shipments on first come first serve basis )
- Allocate shipments (allows logged in user to allocate multiple shipments to driver, shipments must be accepted first)

What would the intuitive options for RESTFul API design for below scenarios? Does adding *mine* or *my* add any value or it is implicit that call is executed in the context of authenticated user?

**Loading shipments**
This is straightforward by designing POST \shipments\

**Available shipments**

Option 1: \my\shipments
Option 2: \availableshipments
Option 3: \shipments?available=yes

**Accept shipments**

Option 1: \my\shipments\acceptance
Option 2: \acceptedshipments
Option 3: \shipments\acceptance

Verb: PUT

Body

```
    "id":
    [
       "10000023",    "10000025",   "10000025"
    ]
```

**Allocate shipments**

Option 1: \allocatedshipments
Option 2: \shipments\allocated

Verb: PUT

Body

```
"driverid": "12312",
"id" :  
 [
       "10000023",    "10000025",   "10000025"
 ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How would you do that as a website?

Would you tell your users to submit some magic content to some magic URI, or would you offer a webpage where there is a form the user can fill out and just submit?

For a RESTful API, you would describe the pages you have in your application through Media Types, and let the client navigate through the use-cases using links and forms on its own. In this case the client would not need to know URIs, HTTP Methods or what to submit beforehand, because all that is discovered on the fly.

I'm just saying that, because you (or other people reading) may be not aware, that is how it was *supposed* to work. If you don't want to do that, and just want endpoints that do things, return some data, and all of that is hardcoded into the clients, then I guess there's no real difference in any of those options. You have to read the documentation and hardcode the URIs into the client, or even generate it automatically. Would different URIs make any difference there?

Comment: This use case is not suitable for M2M(machine to machine/unattended) use case as there is human judgment required. This Api will be purpose built for User interface.

Comment: You mean it is built for humans? Why don't you use HTML then instead of JSON?

Comment: User interface is SPA(single page application) calling REST Apis using HTTP Verbs and JWT token based authentication.

Comment: None of that disqualifies HTML. I'm just wondering whether you're making it more complex than it needs to be. A lot of times you'll be forced to change both the SPA and Backend at the same time if you do it your way. That is something we want to avoid normally, unless there is a very good reason to the contrary.

Comment: yes, you are right, we are forced to change both the SPA and Backend at the same time. Can you elaborate - how this can be avoided?

Comment: In short, the backend has to produce the HTML(+JavaScript if needed). This fits REST perfectly, which was originally described with HTTP+HTML in mind, but is less suited for SPAs, which sort-of require a data-based boundary. Any time you have a data-based interface or boundary, that is what forces you to change both sides all the time.

Comment: I thought rendering server side html markup was the slowest thing in HTTP Pipeline, What if you need to serve mobile frontend?